# Parabolic regularization for the Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, navier-stokes

I'm looking for some references about a result on the Navier-Stokes equations which seems to be folklore but for which I didn't manage to find a proof. The setting is the following :

Let $Q=\mathbb{R}^3$, or a smooth bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^3$, or an unbounded smooth domain of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (for instance, the half-space)

Take $u_0 \in \mathrm{H}^1_0(Q)$ and a source $f \in L^2_{\mathrm{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^+;L^2(Q))$. Since $u_0 \in L^2(Q)$, we know that there exists a global Leray (weak) solution $u$ the Navier-Stokes equations in $\mathbb{R}^+ \times Q$ with initial condition $u_0$ and source $f$

\begin{align}
\partial_t u + (u \cdot\nabla)u- \Delta u + \nabla p &=f \\ 
\mathrm{div} \, u &=0, \\
u(0)&=u_0
\end{align}
(with $u_{\mid \partial Q}=0$ if $Q$ has a boundary). More precisely, $u$ has an $L^{\infty}_{\mathrm{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^+;L^2(Q)) \cap L^2_{\mathrm{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^+;\mathrm{H}^1_0(Q))$ regularity.

Now, consider such a weak solution $u$. Since $u_0 \in \mathrm{H}^1_0(Q)$, **we can expect more regularity for $u$ if $u_0$ and $F$ are small enough**. I'm concerned with the following result :

There exists a universal constant $C>0$ such that if, for some $T>0$, we have
\begin{align}
\Vert u_0 \Vert_{\mathrm{H}^1(Q)}^2 + \int_0^T \Vert f(s) \Vert_{L^2(Q)}^2 \, \mathrm{d}s \leq C,
\end{align}
then the previous solution $u$ belongs to $L^{\infty}(0,T;\mathrm{H}^1(Q)) \cap L^{2}(0,T;\mathrm{H}^2(Q))$ and for $0 \leq t \leq T$
\begin{align}
\Vert \nabla u(t) \Vert_{L^2(Q)}^2 + \int_0^t \Vert \mathrm{D}^2 u(s) \Vert_{L^2(Q)}^2 \, \mathrm{d}s \lesssim \Vert u_0 \Vert_{\mathrm{H}^1(Q)}^2 +  \int_0^T \Vert f(s) \Vert_{L^2(Q)}^2 \, \mathrm{d}s.
\end{align}

I know how to prove this result in the case where $Q$ is the whole space $\mathbb{R}^3$ (using Fourier analysis) or a smooth bounded domain $\mathbb{R}^3$ (and the proof relies on the Poincaré inequality at some point) but **I don't know how to prove this property for an unbounded smooth domain with boundary in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (again, I'm actually interested in the case of a half-space)**.

In short, a general idea  for the proof is to first consider a smooth solution to the Navier-Stokes equations and to obtain a priori estimate in $L^{\infty}(0,T;\mathrm{H}^1(Q)) \cap L^{2}(0,T;\mathrm{H}^2(Q))$ (essentially by multiplying the system by $\Delta u$ and then integrating) and then to rely on some weak-strong uniqueness principle to show that this estimates actually holds for our weak solution $u$. However, the first step seems not to easy to achieve in generals domains of $\mathbb{R}^3$...

Any remarks or advices are welcomed.